# extract last word in postgresql using regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have some date in rows of a table like this:

```
colname
-------
/test/test/value1
/test/value2
/test:code&/value3
/value4
```

now I want last word of each rows (which are `value1, value2, value3, value4`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` function.

```
regexp_replace('/test/test/value1', '^.*/', '')
```

Comment: thank you. but sounds like, in the first of pattern the ^ is not necessary.